# Table/figure in custom environment

Tags: tables, environments

having a custom defined environment, how would it be possible to have figure/table under the defined environment?

```
\newenvironment{example}[1]{%  
  \begin{exa}[#1]  
}{%  
  \end{exa}  
}
```

and

```
\begin{example}{something}  
\table <----- here it fails (not in outer par mode)  
\end table  
\end{example}
```

Comment: What is this `exa` environment you are using?  Can you post a complete example that can be compiled?  Not the whole of your doc, but just the bare minimum of pacakges etc needed to compile.

Comment: PS use 4 spaces to indent a code block

Comment: Are you looking for `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}`? I guess you don't want to use a `table`-environment here.

Comment: \table ... \endtable should work with a tabular environment inside

Answer (score 2):

This works, but would I use it (this way)? **No**.

For more sophisticated setups, the environment must be used with arguments, preferably with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from `xparse`

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{example}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
A & B
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi,  
example environment is not only for tables, i.e. it can be text/figure/table.  
For this reason i was looking for a universal "structure" of "example" environment definition.

Comment: @SauliusS: Your specification is in fact none. You should edit your question